# Python. Django Rest Framework. How to get a custom Json response?

Tags: python, json, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to raise a message when a condition is met (if ingrediente.saldo <= ingrediente.saldo_minimo) to tell the user that a supply is almost out of stock.

Can you help me figure out how to do that?

views.py

```
class CreateOrderView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    """Esta clase maneja los requests GET y POST."""
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Guarda la info al crear una nueva ORDEN. RESTA del stock. Controla el saldo mínimo.Devuelve el precio sugerido."""

        serializer.save()
        post = self.request.POST
        lista_productos = json.loads(post.get('productos'))
        precio_hora_trabajada = SystemParameters.objects.get(id=1).precio_hora_trabajada

        serializer.instance.costo_total = costo_total_orden(post)
        serializer.instance.save()


        horas_trabajadas_total = 0
        for prod in lista_productos:
            producto = Product.objects.get(pk=prod['id'])
            Products.objects.create(order=serializer.instance,
                                    product=producto, cantidad=prod['cantidad'])
            for ingred in producto.supplies_set.all():
                cantidad_por_ingrediente = producto.supplies_set.get(supply=ingred.supply_id).cantidad
                ingrediente = ingred.supply
                ingrediente.saldo -= cantidad_por_ingrediente*Decimal(prod['cantidad'])
                ingrediente.save()


                if ingrediente.saldo <= ingrediente.saldo_minimo:
                    alerta= 'Alerta: el supply llegó al stock mínimo'
                    content = {'alerta': alerta}
                    return Response(content)
                continue

            horas_trabajadas_total += producto.horas_trabajadas

        serializer.instance.precio_sugerido = (serializer.instance.costo_total*3)+(precio_hora_trabajada*horas_trabajadas_total)
        serializer.instance.save()
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override `create` instead of `perform_create` if you need to send your custom response. Please try the following:

```
class CreateOrderView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    Esta clase maneja los requests GET y POST.
    """
    queryset = Order.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OrderSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Guarda la info al crear una nueva ORDEN. RESTA del stock.
        Controla el saldo mínimo.Devuelve el precio sugerido.
        """
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        # Your code-snippet starts from here
        post = self.request.POST
        lista_productos = json.loads(post.get('productos'))
        precio_hora_trabajada = SystemParameters.objects.get(id=1).precio_hora_trabajada

        serializer.instance.costo_total = costo_total_orden(post)
        serializer.instance.save()

        horas_trabajadas_total = 0
        for prod in lista_productos:
            producto = Product.objects.get(pk=prod['id'])
            Products.objects.create(order=serializer.instance,
                                    product=producto, cantidad=prod['cantidad'])
            for ingred in producto.supplies_set.all():
                cantidad_por_ingrediente = producto.supplies_set.get(supply=ingred.supply_id).cantidad
                ingrediente = ingred.supply
                ingrediente.saldo -= cantidad_por_ingrediente * Decimal(prod['cantidad'])
                ingrediente.save()

                if ingrediente.saldo <= ingrediente.saldo_minimo:
                    alerta = 'Alerta: el supply llegó al stock mínimo'
                    content = {'alerta': alerta}
                    return Response(content)
                continue

            horas_trabajadas_total += producto.horas_trabajadas

        serializer.instance.precio_sugerido = (serializer.instance.costo_total * 3) + (
                    precio_hora_trabajada * horas_trabajadas_total)
        serializer.instance.save()
        # Your code-snippet Ended here

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

see codebase for [ListCreateAPIView](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a251b9379200420062cad9e3c68fde7c0e6b3fdc/rest_framework/generics.py#L234:7).

Comment: Thank you! Adding this **from rest_framework import status** and  **return Response({'orden': serializer.data, 'alerta': alerta}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)** fixed the problem.